# Promise returns undefined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I was trying to build connections with Azure Cosmos DB (mongo API) in NodeJS in ES6. Callback styles still persisted because I could not find examples in ES6 (but ES7). 
In `db.js`

```
export function ReadAll (dbName, collectionName) {
  return ConnectToCollection(dbName, collectionName).then(collection => {
    collection.find({}).then(docs => {
      // docs is not undefined here
      return docs
    })
  })
}

function ConnectToCollection (dbName, collectionName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoClient.connect(
      PRIMARY_CONNECTION_STRING,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
      (err, client) => {
        if (err) reject(new Error(err))
        const db = client.db(dbName)
        const collection = db.collection(collectionName)
        resolve(collection)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

which was called in `index.js`

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  ReadAll(DB_NAME, COLLECTION_NAME_TEMP).then(docs => {
    // but docs here is undefined
    ...
  })
})
```

I still get undefined `docs` too:

```
export function ReadAll (dbName, collectionName) {
  return ConnectToCollection(dbName, collectionName).then(collection => {
      // Even with a return here
      return collection.find({}).toArray(docs => {
        return docs
    })
  })
}
```

why did I get undefined `docs` here?

Answer (score 1):

Shailesh Jha's answer is halfway there. You need to return `collection.find` result to not break the promise chain. You also need to call `toArray` method after `find` because it returns a cursor that doesn't return any items itself without calling `toArray`. So your `ReadAll` method should look like this:

```
function ReadAll(dbName, collectionName) {
    return ConnectToCollection(dbName, collectionName).then(collection => {
        // add toArray method to actually return items
        collection.find({}).toArray().then(docs => {
            // docs is now returned
            return docs
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    export function ReadAll (dbName, collectionName) {
  return ConnectToCollection(dbName, collectionName).then(collection => {
    **return** collection.find({}).then(docs => {
      // docs is not undefined here
      return docs
    })
  })
}
```

Hope this way you can find your docs as you were returning nothing.